# need support for RCPT TO parameter in message.send

Tags: smtp, gmail-api

The SMTP protocol supports the RCPT TO command - there should be an analogous parameter in message.send. I need to do something where the RCPT TO is different from, and must take precedence over, what is in the TO 2822 header and I don't think this can currently be done via the API so I'm having to revert to SMTP. It would be great if the API supports an RCPT TO variable.

Comment: Does the API support BCC? That's where you normally put recipients that aren't in the `To` or `CC` headers.

Answer (score 1):

The API supports BCC.  If you need to fake the To header (e.g. say someone is To or Cc but don't include them in the list of recipients to get the message), I'd be interested in the use case.  SMTP does allow more power but it's also plagued with many problems from a spam/abuse perspective.